# How to move the particular div element to the right

Tags: html, css

Here is the jsfiddle. I need to move the notice div to righttop corner.How to achieve this?
I tried it with float right but not working

https://jsfiddle.net/akhilRT/4hzdbqux/

Please try this out

```css
.notice {
  display: block;
  position: static;
  float: right;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  background-color: green;
  color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 1);
  color: var(--text);
  transition: height .5s ease-in, opacity .5s ease-in;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="notice   is-success x-hidden-focus">
  <p class="alert-title">
    <span class="docon docon-lightbulb" aria-hidden="true">…</span> Tip

  </p>
  <p>
    Using conventional routing with the default route allows you to build the application quickly without having to come up with a new URL pattern for each action you define. For an application with CRUD style actions, having consistency for the URLs across
    your controllers can help simplify your code and make your UI more predictable.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: which div you need to move top?

Comment: it seems to be at the top, what am I missing here?

Comment: @Ranjithv notice div to right top

Comment: @AKHIL NAMBIAR  pls check my below code dude

Comment: Ah I see your question code does not match the fiddle code, perhaps fix that

Answer (score 0):

try like this

**css**

```
    .notice {
   display: block;
position: absolute;
float: right;
border-radius: 6px;
font-size: 1.2rem;
padding: 1rem;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
margin-top: 0;
background-color: green;
color: hsla(0,0%,0%,1);
color: var(--text);
transition: height .5s ease-in, opacity .5s ease-in;
word-wrap: break-word;
word-break: break-word;
top: 0;
right: 0;
max-width: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
    background-color: #2e2e2e
}
.container {
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
p {
    color:white
}
.alert {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 6px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    background-color:green;
    color: hsla(0,0%,0%,1);
    color: var(--text);
    transition: height .5s ease-in, opacity .5s ease-in;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    word-break: break-word;
   
}
.notice {
    display: block;
    position: static;
    float:right;
    border-radius: 6px;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    background-color: green;
    color: hsla(0,0%,0%,1);
    color: var(--text);
    transition: height .5s ease-in, opacity .5s ease-in;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    word-break: break-word;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <div class="well">
                    <form>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>First Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Last Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="last name" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email">Email</label>
                            <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="email" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Register" />
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="alert is-success x-hidden-focus">
                    <p class="alert-title">
                        <span class="docon docon-lightbulb" aria-hidden="true">…</span>
                        Tip

                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Using conventional routing with the default route allows you to build the application quickly without having to come up with a new URL pattern for each action you define. For an application with CRUD style actions, having consistency for the URLs across your controllers can help simplify your code and make your UI more predictable.
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="notice   is-success x-hidden-focus">
                    <p class="alert-title">
                        <span class="docon docon-lightbulb" aria-hidden="true">…</span>
                        Tip

                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Using conventional routing with the default route allows you to build the application quickly without having to come up with a new URL pattern for each action you define. For an application with CRUD style actions, having consistency for the URLs across your controllers can help simplify your code and make your UI more predictable.
                    </p>
                </div>


            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```